# An infinitely-dimensional vector space with an infinitely dimensional kernel and image

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am asked to give an example of a transformation $T: V \to V$ such that $T$ is linear, $V$ is infinitely dimensional, ker$(T)$ is infinitely dimensional, and im$(T)$ is infintely-dimensional.

My instinct is to go with $T: C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}) \to C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$, but I'm having trouble fulfilling this image requirement. I set $T$ up in the following way:

$T(f) = 0$ if $f \in R[x]$, and $T(f) = .....$ otherwise.

The kernel requirement is upheld, because ker$(T)$ = $R[x]$. But what kind of outputs would be infinitely-dimensional? Can someone help me use this kind of example to make a transformation from $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ to $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$?

Thanks.

Comment: Take the map $W \oplus W \to W \oplus W$ given by $(w_1, w_2) \mapsto (w_1, 0)$, where $W$ is any infinite-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Try $T$ with $T(f):=
\text{the even part of } T$, i.e., $T(f)(x):=\frac{f(x)+ f(-x)}{2}$.

Comment: This is really useful, but I'm having trouble justifying what im(T) is. ker(T) is all functions whose even part is 0, or all odd functions. But im(T) directly is all functions "g" that can be written in the form $\frac{1}{2} (f(x) + f(-x))$. What is this set, and what functions cannot be represented in this form? Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: The Image of $T$ equals tbe set of all _even_ continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements of $V$ are sequences $v=(v_1, v_2, \ldots,)$, consider the map
$$(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, \ldots) \mapsto (0, v_2, 0, v_4, 0, v_6, \ldots)$$

Comment: Sorry, this confuses me a little bit. What do you mean "sequences $v = (v_1,...)$?" Give me an example of an element of V, and how is it infinitely-dimensional? Forgive me for the basic question

Comment: @Cjw123 I mean that the elements of $V$ are sequences like that. For example, $(1,0,2,3,1,0,\ldots)$ or $(0,0,1,-1,0,\ldots)$.